# How can I escape data coming from simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
simplexml_load_file($htmlstring)
```

This is my simple pull from a third party database. We started pulling a comments section which unfortunately contains & and a few < which is barfing the xml build. Error is:

```
Unescaped '&lt;' not allowed in attributes values
```

How can I get to those incorrectly formatted results and CDATA them or something before it tried to build the XML set. I have looked all over http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php but dont seem to have the smarts to find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input file is invalid, and you can't influence the third party to fix it, your options are rather limited.

One thing which might be worth trying is using [DOM in HTML mode](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) to load the file. This uses a more forgiving parser, but then creates the same data structure.

The nice thing is that you don't actually have to use the DOM with all its verbosity, because you [can "import" the DOM object into SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php). This doesn't require any re-parsing, because both interfaces use the same data structures internally ([libxml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php)).

From there - assuming this worked - you can carry on as though you'd just run `simplexml_load_file` in the first place.

So instead of this:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($file_path);
```

You'd write this:

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($file_path);
$sxml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
```

Then carry on as you were.

(If you have a string of data instead of a file path, you'd be using `simplexml_load_string()` and `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` respectively.)

Comment: Thanks, So to be clear, you think I can grab it, creating a  file locally with it, scrub that, and then carry on with my simplexml_load_file with the now clean local file?

Comment: @jeynon Not even as complicated as that; see sample code I just added to the answer